# My variables change inside or outside of a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that adds numbers in a list ( list[1,2,3] should return 1+2+3 = 6.

This one doesn't work:

```
def sum_list (list): 
    for number in list:
        old_value=0
        new_value=old_value+number
        old_value=new_value
    return new_value
```

This one does work:

```
def sum_list (list):
    old_value=0
    for number in list:        
        new_value=old_value+number
        old_value=new_value
    return new_value
```

Can anyone explain why the program doesn't work in old_value is within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is logically wrong. You are re initializing the value of old_value to 0 every time the loop runs.

First method only retains the last entry in the list because old_value is always 0.

Comment: I didn't realize values within the loop would be 're initialized' - That's what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

In the first piece of code, `old_value` is set to `0` in every iteration. therefore, the last line in the loop, `old_value=new_value`, does not change anything

Comment: exactly what @gefei said. You could just do sum([1,2,3])